# How to change default colors of React Native Swiper component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-swiper

I'm using this React Native Swiper component: https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper#custom-basic-style--content

I'm having trouble changing the dot color to anything but the default blue. Anyone know how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
<Swiper style={styles.wrapper} loop={true}>
      {rows.map(function(obj, index) {
          return(
            <View style={styles.main} key={index}>
              <Image
                source={{uri: obj.url}}
                style={styles.main} />
            </View>)
      })}
    </Swiper>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This component has a prop named 'dot', which you can change the style of the dot.

```
<View style={{
      backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,.2)', 
      width: 8, 
      height: 8,       
      borderRadius: 4, 
      marginLeft: 3, 
      marginRight: 3, 
      marginTop: 3, 
      marginBottom: 3,}} 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'dot' prop.
You can use the 'activeDot' prop in the same way.

```
<Swiper
    dot={<View style={{backgroundColor:'red', width: 8, height: 8,borderRadius: 4, marginLeft: 3, marginRight: 3, marginTop: 3, marginBottom: 3,}} />}>
</Swiper>
```