# react-native-swiper: Is there a way to custom the style of the dots?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-swiper

I add picture of the dots that I want to change.

[this is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUmCq.png) .

I'm using the [react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper)

Is there a way to change the style(color, size..) for dots in swiper?

```
<Swiper
  style={styles.wrapper}
  showsButtons={false}
  onIndexChanged={this.onSwiperIndexChanged}
  index={this.state.initialIndex} //{list.length - this.state.initialIndex - 1}
>
  {list.map((item, index) => (
    <InfoTable
      key={index}
      headerInfo={item}
      approvers={approvers}
      settings={settings}
    />
  ))}
</Swiper>;
```

Comment: you will have to dig into the code of that library and modify it accordingly.

Comment: @TheRakeshPurohit Nop, they have provided the API

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can

Refer to the document [swiper-pagination](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper#pagination)

#### dot

> Allow custom the dot element.

```
<View
  style={{
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.2)",
    width: 8,
    height: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
    marginLeft: 3,
    marginRight: 3,
    marginTop: 3,
    marginBottom: 3
  }}
/>;
```

Comment: can you show me how to do it in my code ? because i try already and its doesnt work for me

Comment: @mia Could you add some details explanation about the problem you are facing to your question? Or add an online demo?

Comment: i add picture of the dots that i wanna change style of them above in my question

Comment: @mia Guess what, you need to make it clear what's the problem you are facing, rather than add a picture waiting for others to achieve it.   If you have questions adding custom styles to `dot`, I believe I have answered it. If you have further CSS setting problems, explain it in detail with a new question is preferred.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473352/how-to-change-default-colors-of-react-native-swiper-component/70668879#70668879